# Java : Remove seconds from java.sql.Time not working

Tags: java, time, data-conversion

I am working on a Java application in which I am trying to remove the seconds part of `java.sql.Time` object before printing it. I tried using `SimpleDateFormat` and provide `HH:MM` and `HH:mm`, but it gives me weird results, which includes the time zone. How can I get String from Time object which doesn't have seconds. I can perform REGEX and simply remove the part after 2nd `:`, but I was hoping there is something better than that. Thank you.

Code :

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
 Date formattedDate = sdf.parse(TimeObject.getTargetTime().toString());
    String msgToPring= "Message "+formattedDate;
```

Current output :

```
 Thu Jan 01 14:15:00 IST 1970
```

I tried a few suggestions on other SO links, but none of them seem to address this.

Comment: A `Date` has no format, it's just a number of milliseconds since the epoch. If you want to format a Time, use sdf.format, not sdf.parse !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing the date (Create a new Date Object from a String), but what you actually have to do is format it (Create a String representation from an existing date):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
String dateString = sdf.format(TimeObject.getTargetTime());
String msgToPring = "Message "+dateString;
```

Note: This will only create a String representation of your date Object printing out Hours and Seconds. Your original Date object will not change and stil have its full date information.

Comment: This worked my friend. I will accept your answer in 5minutes, as that's the time limit SO has added before I can accept your answer. Thank you!!!